# Having trouble with ODBC Driver for Access database

Tags: php, ms-access, odbc

I have created an intranet php site using WampServer on my home test environment where everything works fine.  I then tried to install it on the production server, again with WampServer installed, but when I try to connect to the database, I get an error:

> ERROR: SQL STATE[IM002] SQLDriverConnect:0 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified.

I have the php_pdo_odbc extension enabled.

Here is the code I'm having trouble with:

```
$dbName2013 = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/Ridley/RLCompRepair.accdb";
try {
    $db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};;Dbq=$dbName2013");
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "ERROR: ".$e->getMessage();
}
```

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Chris

Comment: could [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17841948/pdo-odbc-data-source-name-not-found-and-no-default-driver-specified) be it?

Comment: Did you install the Access ACE driver on the server?

Comment: [YII, MS Access how can i use it together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25184366/yii-ms-access-how-can-i-use-it-together/52843216#52843216)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to connect with DNS-less database.
create a Windows ODBC DNS

In Windows go to "Administrative Tools" and Select "Data Sources"
Go to File DSN select Add
select Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)
Select Next, type in a Data source Name
select "Next" then Finish
You should be in ODBC Microsoft Access Setup
select "Select" navigate to your .mdb and select it.
select "OK"

In your PHP try this:

```
$connect = odbc_connect("[data source name given]", "user", "password");
$connect = odbc_connect("myaccess", "", "");
if($connect === false){echo "did not work<br>";exit}
echo "success";
```